# OpenAM call back in case of load balancer

Tags: openam, cross-domain-policy, opensso

While going through the openAm document I found that when a session is invalidated by admin, openAm notifies the agent about this, but suppose I have multiple copy of my application which are situated in geographically distributed location sitting behind a load balancer, how will the particular agent will be notified in case of a session invalidation happening, I guess sticky session wont help in this scenario as no request is going from my application side.

Answer (score 0):

Every instance of your application has to be protected by an agent and ever agent has a separate agent profile where the unique notification URL has to be specified. Create an agent group and add all agents to that group, only keep the notification URL unique. If OpenAM can not reach the notification URLs , agents have to be configured in polling mode (minimal polling time  ... one minute).